# Excel: What is the difference between the functions correl and pearson?

Tags: excel-formula, correlation, pearson-correlation

The Microsoft documentation for the functions [correl](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/correl-function-995dcef7-0c0a-4bed-a3fb-239d7b68ca92) and [pearson](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pearson-function-0c3e30fc-e5af-49c4-808a-3ef66e034c18) both say that they calculate correlation coefficients and they both state the algebraic formula that the function uses in its calculation, and those two formulae are identical! So are those functions actually equivalent, or is one (or both) of those documentation pages wrong? If they are not equivalent, what is each one actually doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few references around the web that basically say

- Excel versions earlier than 2003 should use `CORREL` since `PEARSON`
  was later found to have rounding errors
- Excel versions after 2003 can use either and produce the same result.

Microsoft article (the one that matters):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/statistical-functions-rsq

Other references:

1. (Includes a link to a dead ~~Microsoft article of yesteryear~~) https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/what-is-the-difference-between-pearson-and-correl.158607/#post-775183
2. (Towards the bottom under "Things to remember about the CORREL Function") https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/functions/correl-function-correlation/

Comment: Thanks Chris. Interesting that it is explained in a troubleshooting article about function `rsq`, which is just the square of `pearson`, and is not explained in the function documentation articles about `correl`, `pearson`, or `rsq`. Also, I wonder why Excel ever had `pearson` if it was just an error-prone version of `correl`, unless it was faster than `correl`, which is not stated in any of those references.

Comment: The article at the dead link in the forum answer linked as your item 1 is available at https://web.archive.org/web/20031101170433/http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=828888 . It seems to say about the same as the troubleshooting article you linked to, along with a lot of other information about improvements in the stats functions in Excel 2003.